# Python unicode, UCS4 build or UCS2 build

Tags: python, c++

On my Linux machine, directly execute python command, it shows that my Python is UCS4 build.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  8 2018, 17:43:28)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> if sys.maxunicode > 65535:
...     print 'UCS4 build'
... else:
...     print 'UCS2 build'
...
UCS4 build
```

However, when I call python in C++ program using

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("if sys.maxunicode > 65535:\n    print 'UCS4 build'\nelse:\n    print 'UCS2 build'");
```

it prints "UCS2 build".
Other information from the python called by c++ are:

> platform:Linux-2.6.32_1-19-0-0-x86_64-with-centos-6.3-Final
>
> ('Python', '2.7.5 (default, Apr 13 2016, 14:25:24)
>
> [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]')
>
> ('Python', '******/venv')

I have double checked the python executable path. They are from the same path, but python version and gcc version are different.

Anyone know the reason of this strange sympotom?

Comment: how did you install python?

Comment: python virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this problem. Using ldd command, I found that libpython2.7.so.1.0 pointed to a wrong default path, not the one printed before. Correct the LD_LIBRARY_PATH solved this confusion.....